# PHP undefined reference to `ts_resource_ex'

Tags: php

I'm trying to recompile PHP to include pgsql and to enable ZTS, but I keep getting a recurring error code:

```
sudo ./configure --prefix=/home/me/php --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-pgsql=shared --enable-maintainer-zts
sudo make
```

and the error:

> ext/standard/.libs/info.o: In function `php_info_printf':
>   /home/me/workspace/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/standard/info.c:83:
>   undefined reference to`ts_resource_ex' ext/standard/.libs/info.o: In
>   function `php_info_print':
>   /home/me/workspace/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/standard/info.c:97:
>   undefined reference to`ts_resource_ex' ext/standard/.libs/info.o: In
>   function `php_info_print_html_esc':
>   /home/me/workspace/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/standard/info.c:69:
>   undefined reference to`ts_resource_ex' ext/standard/.libs/info.o: In
>   function `php_print_gpcse_array':
>   /home/me/workspace/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/standard/info.c:204:
>   undefined reference to`executor_globals_id'
>   ext/standard/.libs/info.o: In function `php_print_info':
>   /home/me/workspace/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/standard/info.c:869:
>   undefined reference to`executor_globals_id' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did you ran `make clean` before running make again?

Comment: I'm not sure. Since posting this (and forgetting about it), I've since figured out a workaround: setting the resource max, and running in different procecesses.

Comment: Ok. I just crossed this issue myself and `make clean` worked for me.

Comment: Good to know. You should put it up as an answer.

Comment: `make clean` worked for me as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not clear what causes the problem but `make clean` resolves it.